# Split String C#

Tags: c#, .net, string

how to split a character string "`test1&test2`" to  "`test1`" "`test2`" without delimeter "`&`" in C#

```
function("test1&test2","&") == "test1"

function("test1&test2","&") == "test2"
```

Comment: are you familiar with the `string.Split()` Method?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+split+string+with+delimiter

Comment: This question shows no research effort. Type "Split String C#" into Google and there are plenty of results, including ample documentation of useful approaches. The #1 thing we expect is for you to [do your own research](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) before asking a question.

Comment: Are both of those supposed to return `true`? If so, I want to know the implementation of `function`!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users

Comment: @Xaqron Everything the top answer says.

Answer (score 3):

[`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) returns a `string[]`, the first element is "test1" and the second is "test2":

```
string[] split = "test1&test2".Split('&');
string test1 = split[0];
string test2 = split[1];
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/oFVKOX)

Answer (score 2):

[`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method is what you're looking for:

```
string input = "test1&test2";
string[] parts = input.Split(new[] { '&' });
```

Comment: I believe you mean `&` as your delimiter. This would give you { "test1&test2" }

Comment: No need to build a char array, string.Split takes a params so passing a simple char '&' works as well

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] parts = "test1&test2".Split(new char[]{'&'});
```

simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried?

Nominally just use `String.Split`:

```
var s = "test1&test2";
var results = s.Split(new char[] {'&'});
```

Comment: No need to build a char array, string.Split takes a params so passing a simple char '&' works as well

Comment: @Steve Yes you are right, I'm so used to doing it this way I forget.

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple `string.Split`

```
string example = "test1&test2";
string[] parts = example.Split('&');
Console.WriteLine(parts[0]);    
Console.WriteLine(parts[1]);
```

[Docs on String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx)

Note to downvoter that String.Split takes a `params char[]`, so also passing a simple char works....